# Tensorflow 2 tf.function input_signature for a list input

Tags: python, tensorflow, model

In order to export my model with the `saved_model` api, I need to define the `input_signature` of each method intended to be called after loading. I don't know how to tell that the input is a list with variable length (as it is for `tf.keras.Model.call` for instance).

There is a list of unanswered questions about `input_signature` on SO:

- [Use dictionary in tf.function input_signature in Tensorflow 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60827999/use-dictionary-in-tf-function-input-signature-in-tensorflow-2-0)
- [tf.function input_signature for distributed dataset in tensorflow 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58484924/tf-function-input-signature-for-distributed-dataset-in-tensorflow-2-0)
- [TensorFlow 2 tf.function decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60059410/tensorflow-2-tf-function-decorator)

and also this one about `*args`: [TensorFlow 2 How to use *args in tf.function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59167107/tensorflow-2-how-to-use-args-in-tf-function) but it does not handle the problem of `saved_model`.

Comment: u found the answer yet?

Comment: didn't work on it that much

Comment: i now just use @tf.function without input_signature, and fit the model this way: model.fit(x=[inp1,inp2,etc], y=exp)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use a Tensor instead of a list as input?

Then specify a `[None]` dimension in `tf.TensorSpec` to allow for flexibility in trace reuse.

Since TensorFlow matches tensors based on their shape, using a `None` dimension as a wildcard will allow Functions to reuse traces for variably-sized input. Variably-sized input can occur if you have sequences of different length, or images of different sizes for each batch.

```
@tf.function(input_signature=(tf.TensorSpec(shape=[None], dtype=tf.int32),))
def g(x):
  print('Tracing with', x)
  return x

# No retrace!
print(g(tf.constant([1, 2, 3])))
print(g(tf.constant([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])))
```

```
Tracing with Tensor("x:0", shape=(None,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([1 2 3], shape=(3,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([1 2 3 4 5], shape=(5,), dtype=int32)
```